# Where do items created with the Path of Conjuring appear?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

The rules concerning the items are simple, but the way the items are created is not clear (this is from the 20th Anniversary edition).

The vampire can create a simple form (in the case I'm considering a wooden stake) without rolling and can spend 3 blood points to make it permanent.

My question is: where does the object appear? I guess they cannot summon an item from a hundred meters away, but should another vampire be close, say five meters, could the Tremere vampire summon a wooden stake in the other vampire's heart? Or inside his pocket to hide the fact that it's been summoned?

Given the circumstances it could be very tricky but powerful, though I would understand if it's considered too much.

I wonder if there's an "official" explanation in a rulebook somewhere or if it's only up to the storyteller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the book and applying the rules as read there are no rules stating where you can create the object.  So yes, it is a decision of the storyteller.

Even more, it doesn’t state that you cannot conjure something inside something else (like a wooden stake inside a vampire heart), although, it doesn’t state that you can neither.  The only thing merely related is the ‘Out of thin air’ in the background explanation of the path.

The book is quite big so it could be that somewhere there are more rules about this, but, if this is the case, I haven’t find them.

As I played and storytelled a few Tremere over the years I can only tell you that, in my experience,  the Tremere conjured things within arm’s reach, or sometimes within sight reach, depending on your or your storyteller view, and always in ‘empty’ space.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any official rulings but I would say that it is conjured on their person, usually held in their hand or in the case of bigger things on the floor in front of them, I would however allow them to conjure a stake in the other vampires heart if they actually put their hand on the other vampires chest, again not an official ruling just what I would allow personally :)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. This question is tagged [rules-as-written](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written), so a quote from the rulebook to back up your answer would be very useful. Other than that, check the [FAQ](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) if you have any questions about how the site works and feel free to [join us in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) when you have 20+ rep.